# How can I get the "REAL" column / Table names from a sql server View query

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-view, information-schema

I'am trying to write a query to retrieve the "real" column names as they are defined by the table definition, but through the view they are used in.

[Find the complete document with all the queries and screen dumps of the results I'am looking for](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8LhY-7Tjj7TYmVHX2lSb0toUlk/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

View columns dont always map to a table column. consider the following (made up) view definition.

```
CREATE VIEW MadeUp
AS    
SELECT 
    GETDATE() AS CurrDate,
    0 AS Zero,
    object_id + schema_id AS SumId,
    name + type_desc COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS SomeString,
    ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.tables ) AS NumTables    
FROM sys.objects;
```

Your best bet might be to examine your view definitions manually to determine what you need.

Comment: It is an existing system with +- 1000 tables and +-250 complex views. To change the views to not link in other views is not worth the effort.  The reason why I need the "REAL" table / column names of the selection in the views is so that I can apply "other business logic" that is linked to the "actual database field" in our database objects.

I know it is not the best practice to link views inside views, but in our situation that is something we can't change.

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of this madeup view?  I ran it, and the results make no sense to me...

Comment: I was trying to point out that view columns often don't map directly to a table column.  A column in a view may not resolve to a single table column or even to a set of table columns.  The example I provided wasn't a good one.  A better example might be a view with a FullName column that is the concatenation of FirstName and LastName columns.  What result would you want from your query in that case?

Comment: I understand what you getting at. Thanks.  You see we have field level security that is applied on table column level, and if it is used in a view it must be applied there as well.  If it is a concatenation of fields we can return NULL for that field or the AliasName so that we can apply security manually for that Alias name in the VIEW.  And maybe an extra column that indicate that this alias is NotLinkedToTableColumn so that I know how to treat the security

Comment: Have you considered building a Data Dictionary table?  One row for each view column with additional columns for supplementary information. Do the initial population with the queries you have then fill in the rest manually. I know this isn't your prefered approach, but I don't think you are going to be able to write a query that tells you everything you want to know.

Comment: JSR,  I'am trying to work something out in the lines of a program that can build up this list for me. Thanks for the advice.  If only the View could return an "Column_Ordinal_Number" of the "original table column" or 0 if it was a concatenation or madeup column, that would have helped me alot.